# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uisearchbar, exc-bad-access

```
//Set all cancel buttons in search bars to "Done"
id searchBarButton = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7) {
    [searchBarButton setTitle:@"Done"];
} else {
    //Can't do anything here or i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}
```

This is giving a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when called in `viewDidLoad` only on iOS 7 Gold Master and newer. iOS 7 beta 6 and older is fine.

Is there a different way to do this in iOS 7?

`NSLog("%@", searchBarButton)` results in this on iOS7:

`2013-10-01 16:14:25.972 MP Staging[12293:a0b] <_UIBarItemAppearance:0x1aaf72d0> <Customizable class: UIBarButtonItem> when contained in (
    UISearchBar
) with invocations (null)>`

and this on iOS 6

`<_UIBarItemAppearance: 0x1c671aa0>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTitle` will fail in iOS7.

Try below code from [this](http://blog.tallisoft.dk/blog/2013/06/16/changing-cancel-button-title-in-uisearchbar/) blog:

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    UIButton *cancelButton;
    UIView *topView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    if (cancelButton) {
      //Set the new title of the cancel button
        [cancelButton setTitle:@"Annuller" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: If I put a breakpoint at `cancelButton = (UIButton*)subview` it never reaches it

Comment: I changed the `self.searchDisplayController.searchBar` to `self.venueSearchBar` and added a breakpoint. The two subview classes are `UISearchBarBackground` and `UISearchBarTextField`

Comment: Ok try the update now, you need to put this code in `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` delegate.

Comment: If i put this code in `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` it doesn't work, but if I put it in `searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch` then it shows "cancel" for a second then fades to "Done"

Comment: I put the code into `searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString` and it actually gives me exactly the effect I'm looking for. It says "cancel" until you start typing, and then it says done when you start

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this without any problems in 7.1, however, it does seem to crash on 7.0.x (device and sim) - hopefully this means they've brought the property back in 7.1, but it also means that we have to use one of the above subview traversing hacks for the interim versions.

```
    id barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar = [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil];
    [barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15],
                                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]
                                                             } forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setTitle:@"Done"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UIBarButtonItem`'s `title` property is not available through the `UIAppearance` proxy.

I don't know why it was working in iOS 6, but it's definitely not supposed to.

The only alternative you seem to have is to "hack" the `UISearchBar` by crawling its subviews looking for the button and setting the title, but:

- it's **very** fragile, as any implementation change to the subviews structure will break your code
- it's not global you will have to do this on any `UISearchBar` instance

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18948489/846273) you can perform this "hack" in the `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:` method of `UISearchDisplayDelegate` like follows:

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
     [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];

    UIButton *cancelButton;
    UIView *topView = theSearchBar.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    if (cancelButton) {
        [cancelButton setTitle:@"YourTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the best practice for setting the cancel button text on ios6 and ios7 then?

Comment: If i put this code in `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` it doesn't work, but if I put it in `searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch` then it shows "cancel" for a second then fades to "Done"