# UISearchController change 'Cancel' button title

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

How we can change the title of cancel button in search controller?

[image]

Comment: I have written an answer to this topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206757/how-to-change-textcolor-of-cancel-button-of-uisearchbar-in-ios7. Just use the SHSearchBar Cocoapod which is not such a pain in the ass like the UISearchBar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the "Cancel" Button in search bar using this-

```
for (UIView *view in searchBar.subviews)
{
    for (id subview in view.subviews)
    {
        if ( [subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] )
        {
            [subview setEnabled:YES];
            UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subview;
            [cancelButton setTitle:@"hi" forState:UIControlStateNormal];


            NSLog(@"enableCancelButton");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

The solution provided above could change with new iOS releases. Here is a better approach:

```
[searchBar setValue:@"customString" forKey:@"_cancelButtonText"];
```

Comment: `_cancelButtonText` is private, it may also change with new iOS releases if Apple decides to rename it, and because it's private they can safely presume that nobody is using this name in their apps

Comment: I found this value can only be changed once as well. Any other solution where I can change the text (language) dynamically?

Comment: @JoshuaVidamo no its not only once, whenever you will call the above method, it will be changed. What exactly is your question?

Comment: This throws an exception when built on the iOS 13 SDK and the app is run on iOS 13. Is there an updated solution?

Comment: @user102008 use the Appearance solution mentioned above.

Answer (score 13):

The Swift equivalent of Burhanuddin Sunelwala answer did the trick for me!

```
self.searchBar.setValue("custom string", forKey: "cancelButtonText")
```

Thanks to Burhanuddin Sunelwala for putting me in the right direction!

Comment: Worked for me, iOS 15, XCode 15

Answer (score 4):

Worth noting, that the preferred method for changing the Cancel button title is now via appearances (got the idea from an another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522163/511878):

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UISearchBar class]]] setTitle:@"Annuler"];
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the appearance proxy of the UISearchBar. You can find an example here - [How to change the default text of Cancel Button which appears in the UISearchBar +iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536151/how-to-change-the-default-text-of-cancel-button-which-appears-in-the-uisearchbar/14509280#14509280)

Answer (score 2):

swift version:

```
for view:UIView in (searchView?.subviews)!
{
        for subView:UIView in (view.subviews)
        {
            if ( subView is UIButton )
            {
                let cancelBut = subView as! UIButton

                //do stuff with cancelButton here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (UIView *subView in SearchBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;

        [cancelButton setTitle:@"TitleString" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController,UISearchResultsUpdating {
        func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
            //write your code here
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var navItem: UINavigationItem!
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
            searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *){
                navigationItem.searchController = searchController
                UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).title = "new title"
            }
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**swift 4 & 5**

The *best and simple* way that worked for me is this snippet of code:

```
if let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    cancelButton.setTitle("Annuler", for: .normal)
}
```

You can modify more properties like this:

```
if let cancelButton = searchBar.value(forKey: "cancelButton") as? UIButton {
    cancelButton.setTitle(<your_string>, for: <UIControlState>)
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(<your_uicolor>, for: <UIControlState>)
    cancelButton.setAttributedTitle(<your_nsattributedstring>, for: <UIControlState>)
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You also need to have the `searchBar setShowsCancelButton` before the procedure.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [theSearchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
    for (UIView *subView in theSearchBar.subviews){
        if([subView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
            [(UIButton*)subView setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** also use UIButton to avoid problems with Apple!

Answer (score 0):

Swift **4.2, 4.0+**

A custom `class` that supports many customizations with the below results is added in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51345642).

[image]