# Cancel Button in UISearchBar issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

I have implemented search bar in my app with custom(localized) title.

for the first time when I tap on search it shows cancel button as follow:

**First Time**

[image]

**Second Time** When I press cancel button & again tap on Search Bar, it looks fine.

[image]

**My code**

```
   - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{

    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];


    UIButton *cancelButton;
    UIView *topView = search.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    if (cancelButton) {
        [cancelButton setTitle:Localized(@"Cancel") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your `NSLocalizedString` with `UIAppearance`:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:Localized(@"Cancel") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

swift

```
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitle("v1_cancel", for: .normal)
```

(which no longer works in modern ios)
this one 
[Change UISearchBar cancel button text in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990854/change-uisearchbar-cancel-button-text-in-ios-8)
is up to date

Comment: How this should be in swift 4,

Comment: @Antony I'd suggest to look up the documentation of UIAppearance in Swift and translate the line of code

Answer (score 2):

It's working for me:

```
if (cancelButton) {
    [cancelButton setTitle:Localized(@"Cancel") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [search setNeedsLayout];
    [search layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but sorry to say I accepted another answer  for shorter code ...

Answer (score 0):

I had translate the [Jasper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31024703/6296) answer in swift 4:

```
UIButton.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
```