# iOS Appcelerator Studio: How to translate Cancel button on searchbar

Tags: ios, appcelerator, searchbar, appcelerator-titanium

I'd like to know, how to translate SearchBar's Cancel button. I found that overwrite Localization native development region in info.plist might help, but it's not working for me. For Delete button in table view, there is simple option to change that "Delete" string. But I can't find anything that works for searchbar. Thank you

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow!  It will be easier to provide help if you can post some code samples.  SO is not a coding service, but if you have something you're working on, we are more than happy to help fix it or show you how to add capability.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Titanium and seems to require a "hack" in Obj-C/Swift as well:
[How to change the default text of Cancel Button which appears in the UISearchBar +iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536151/how-to-change-the-default-text-of-cancel-button-which-appears-in-the-uisearchbar)

You could do a Feature Request [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org). Check if it has already been requested before you create a new ticket. Refer to this question and also link back to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Thank you Fokke for your suggestion, I created New feature request here: [link](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7977)https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-7977

Answer (score 0):

PR is ready and will be part of the Titanium Mobile SDK 6.0.0: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20295

Thanks for reporting!